# Kendo TabStrip with KendoGrid inside using JavaScript for Events handling

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have simple page with Kendo TabStrip inside

```
<div id="main-view" class="k-content">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("main-view-tabstrip")
            .Items(tabstrip =>
                {
                    tabstrip.Add().Text("My Notices").LoadContentFrom("MyNotices", "Notice").Selected(true);
                }))
</div>
```

It loads content for me on demand, querying the `NoticeController`. `NoticeController` has `MyNotices` action with return me `PartialView`.

```
public PartialViewResult MyNotices()
{
    // put some values into ViewData

    return PartialView();
}
```

The PartialView itseld looks like this:

```
<div style="margin: 20px; height: 700px;">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<NoticeViewModel>(Model)
      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fullScreen" })
      .Name("NoticesList")
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(x => x.UniqueId).Title("UniqueId");
              columns.Bound(x => x.FormName).Title("Form");
              columns.Bound(x => x.Revision).Title("Revision");
              columns.Bound(x => x.Language).Title("Language");
              columns.Bound(x => x.Status).Title("Status");
          }
      )
      .Pageable()
      .Scrollable()
      .Sortable()
      .Selectable()
      .ToolBar(
          toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("New")
      )
        .Editable(
            ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                .TemplateName("NoticeCreate")
                .Window(w => w.Title("Create Notice")
                    .Name("createNoticeWindow1")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "createNoticeWindow" })
                    .Modal(true)
                    )
                .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true)
                )
      .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                          .PageSize(25)
                                          .ServerOperation(true)
                                          .Read("List", "Notice")
                                          .Create("NoticeCreate", "Notice")
                                          .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))
                                          .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.UniqueId))

      ))
</div>

<script>
    function errorHandler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I run the code I receive JS error, that `errorHandler` cannot be found. As you can see I have it inside my `PartialView`.

```
<script>
    function errorHandler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

So the question is how to use javascript inside partial view, when you show it inside TabStrip?

When I remove `.Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))` from the grid, everything work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed the issue, I do not why, but when I put java script block at the beginning it starts to work.

So if someone meet such issue just put `<script/>` block before declaring `Kendo.Grid()`.

Comment: I've seen this behavior as well with Kendo and mvc server wrappers, re: JS events that are declared in the server side wrapper need to be written above the wrapper.

Comment: If you open the console during the page loading, you will probably see an error similar to "errorHandler is not declared".
This is because as the page is loaded, the Kendo widget will look for the function, and if it's declared below, it means that the grid won't be able to find it because it still have to be parsed.